# Issues with Empty String Values in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm using an update statement to replace any Null or empty string values with "No Cost Center". The data that I have imported into the table has numerous blank/empty string values and when I run the code below, it affects 0 rows:

```
Update [dbo].[Import_tbl_Inventory] Set [dbo].[Import_tbl_Inventory].[User Defined Label 4] = 'No Cost Center'
    Where [dbo].[Import_tbl_Inventory].[User Defined Label 4] is Null or [dbo].[Import_tbl_Inventory].[User Defined Label 4] = ''
```

Is there something other than NULL and Empty String values that I need to be checking for?

EDIT:
Upon further review, I decided to right click the table and select `Edit top Rows`. Here I discovered that each row in the `User Defined Label 4` column actually contains spaces. I was able to delete the spaces out of the first 2 rows manually, but any rows after that give me a message saying `Data in row was not committed. The row values updated or deleted either do not make to the row unique or they alter multiple rows`

I'm only altering one row at a time, and there is no reason this should have anything to do with making the row unique. Now sure what's going on here.

Comment: We can't really answer that question.  We don't know your data.

Comment: Does the corresponding `SELECT`-only statement return any rows?

Comment: Your query looks ok, but note that it will not affect rows where column `[User Defined Label 4]` contains a string of one or more space characters. -- such strings are non-null and not equal to the empty string.  Perhaps that's what you really have.

Comment: @JohnBollinger That sounds like it could be the issue, is there a way to account for that?

Comment: @Jcmoney1010, the `RTRIM()` function (or `LTRIM()`) should convert a string of whitespace to an empty string.  To account for column values containing non-empty strings of whitespace, trim them before comparing them to the empty string.

Comment: LEN() returns 0 even if column contains spaces and also trims trailing spaces

Comment: You could also have nonprintable characters like tabs or line feeds

Comment: @HLGEM you had it right! The issue was that the column was full of line feeds that I was unable to see. If you want to post this as an answer I will give you the credit. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check for unprintable characters like tab and line feed

Answer (score 1):

A "blank" string could be a nonempty string of whitespace characters, which might not be easy to distinguish visually from an empty string.  Depending on how you view it, maybe not from `NULL`, either.  To include rows having such values in your update, you can trim them before comparing with the empty string:

```
Update [dbo].[Import_tbl_Inventory]
Set [dbo].[Import_tbl_Inventory].[User Defined Label 4] = 'No Cost Center'
Where [dbo].[Import_tbl_Inventory].[User Defined Label 4] is Null
  or RTRIM([dbo].[Import_tbl_Inventory].[User Defined Label 4]) = ''
```

You could use `LTRIM()` instead of you prefer, but you don't need both because if the string contains only whitespace then passing it to either `LTRIM()` or `RTRIM()` will yield an empty string.

Comment: Hmmm after trying all the suggestions, including this one, I'm still receiving the same issue.

Comment: @Jcmoney1010, then you'll have to present some actual data that exhibit the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can try `LTRIM` and `RTRIM` in your Column and Check the `LEN`

```
Update [dbo].[Import_tbl_Inventory] Set
[dbo].[Import_tbl_Inventory].[User Defined Label 4] = 'No Cost Center'
Where 
LEN(RTRIM(LTRIM(ISNULL([dbo].[Import_tbl_Inventory].[User Defined Label 4],''))))=0
```

You can use `REPLACE`

```
  Update [dbo].[Import_tbl_Inventory] Set
    [dbo].[Import_tbl_Inventory].[User Defined Label 4] = 'No Cost Center'
    Where 
  LEN(REPLACE(ISNULL( [dbo].[Import_tbl_Inventory].[User Defined Label 4],''),' ',''))=0
```

Comment: No need to REPLACE. LEN function trims all trailing spaces before counting.

Comment: This is still resulting in 0 rows affected.

Comment: run `select * from [dbo].[Import_tbl_Inventory] where LEN(ISNULL([dbo].[Import_tbl_Inventory].[User Defined Label 4],''))=0`
and tell us the rows return

Comment: @Ajmot it didn't return any rows.

Comment: so, that's it . your table doesn't contain any rows with NULL or empty string value.
then what you want to do??
your question is not clear. @Jcmoney1010

Comment: @Ajmot My original questions was, outside of Nulls and Empty String Values, what else should I be looking for if the value is Blank? I have an entire column of blanks, obviously from my original question I checked both Nulls and ('') values, but am still having issues. What I want is to find out what is causing those Blanks so I can replace them with 'No Cost Center'

Comment: Nobody knows except you,replace whatever you wan to.
we can't say without seeing the proper data and clear explanation.

Comment: @Ajmot I think you are confusing my intentions with this question. I was not asking anyone to to simply hand me the answer to my specific problem, obviously I would have to post my entire data set for that. I was simply asking for some ideas of what it could be, from people who may have ran into this issue before. I appreciate your attempt to help.

Answer (score 0):

A little cleaner without or

```
Update [dbo].[Import_tbl_Inventory] Set [dbo].[Import_tbl_Inventory].[User Defined Label 4] = 'No Cost Center'
    Where len(isNull([dbo].[Import_tbl_Inventory].[User Defined Label 4], '')) = 0
```

Comment: This still results in the same issue